# How to Convert Json Object to C# Class Object

Tags: .net, json, c#-4.0

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "User1",
            "email": "support@korewireless.com",
            "phone": "+12049987456",
            "status": "Active",
            "title": "Mr"
        },
        {
            "name": "User2",
            "email": "info@korewireless.com",
            "phone": "+12040147456",
            "status": "Active",
            "title": "Mr"
        },
        {
            "name": "User3",
            "email": "help@korewireless.com",
            "phone": "+12040787456",
            "status": "Active",
            "title": "Ms"
        }
    ]
}
```

Tried Converting this json object to a List but it is only having null values

```
var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(jsonData);
```

How can i Parse it to a Class Object ?

Comment: You can use `Newtonsoft` json library and parse the json to C# class -  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to deserialize that particular json string you need to define a root object that contain the list of your users.

For example:

```
public class ListRoot
{ 
    public List<User> users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{ 
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

And now you can call

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListRoot>(jsonData);
foreach (User u in data.users)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"User:name={u.name}, phone={u.phone}, email={u.email}");
}
```

Of course, if you can control the production of the json data, you could have a lot simpler approach preparing a json data like this

```
[
    {
        "name": "User1",
        "email": "support@korewireless.com",
        "phone": "+12049987456",
        "status": "Active",
        "title": "Mr"
    },
    {
        "name": "User2",
        "email": "info@korewireless.com",
        "phone": "+12040147456",
        "status": "Active",
        "title": "Mr"
    },
    {
        "name": "User3",
        "email": "help@korewireless.com",
        "phone": "+12040787456",
        "status": "Active",
        "title": "Ms"
    }
]
```

that gives you the ability to call directly

```
List<User> users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(jsonData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should convert to List of object, because your json is enumeration of users objects.
For example: 
`var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(jsonData);`

Comment: Did you try your answer with the json data proposed by the OP?

Comment: Json can be tried at http://json2csharp.com/ . Other think is what is the User class, because we don`t have the code.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your `User` class. Please provide the code.

Your json looks more like the representation of `List<User>`. If so you have to deserialize via `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(json)`.